# FacebookApiException needs to apply security to a method it doesn't override?

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm building a very crude facebook application as a school project and I've come across the most interesting error. When attempting to make any call to FacebookApp.Api() involving "me" I get the following exception:

> System.TypeLoadException: Inheritance
>   security rules violated while
>   overriding member:
>   Facebook.FacebookApiException.GetObjectData(System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo,
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext)'.
>   Security accessibility of the
>   overriding  method must match the
>   security accessibility of the method
>   being overriden.

Stack Trace:

```
[TypeLoadException: Inheritance security rules violated while overriding member: 'Facebook.FacebookApiException.GetObjectData(System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo, System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext)'. Security accessibility of the overriding method must match the security accessibility of the method being overriden.]
   Facebook.FacebookApp.WithMirrorRetry(Func`1 body) in d:\Projects\facebooksdk\src\Facebook\FacebookApp.cs:758
   Facebook.FacebookApp.OAuthRequest(Uri uri, IDictionary`2 parameters, HttpMethod httpMethod) in d:\Projects\facebooksdk\src\Facebook\FacebookApp.cs:545
   Facebook.FacebookApp.Graph(String path, IDictionary`2 parameters, HttpMethod httpMethod) in d:\Projects\facebooksdk\src\Facebook\FacebookApp.cs:529
   Facebook.FacebookAppBase.Api(String path, IDictionary`2 parameters, HttpMethod httpMethod) in d:\Projects\facebooksdk\src\Facebook\FacebookAppBase.cs:415
   Facebook.FacebookAppBase.Api(String path) in d:\Projects\facebooksdk\src\Facebook\FacebookAppBase.cs:350
   Callback.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) +622
   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +14
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +35
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +91
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +74
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2207
```

As far as I can tell, the error comes from the fact that FacebookApiException is overriding Exception's getDataObject and not doing so with the correct security. However, I don't see FacebookApiException overriding the method at all in the source.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using the release download 4.0.2 or building from the source?

Comment: I'm using the release version, but I didn't see any changes in FacebookApiException. Am I missing something?

Comment: What platform are you running this on?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug in version 4.0.2 of the Facebook C# SDK. The bug is fixed in code and will be fixed in the next release. The fix is to run the App in full trust or to use the most recent build from source control.